# Pipe erratic behaviour in linux / MSVC 2012

Tags: c++, gnuplot

I have a particle system for which I basically track coordinates. Up to now I was outputting all the coordinates in files, then plotting them with a gnuplot script and using ffmpeg to create a video out of the PNGs. To skip all the file I/O, I tried with OpenGL first to no avail, so I thought of setting up a pipe to gnuplot.

I do it like this in MSVC 2012:

```
FILE *gnuplotpipe = _popen(GNUPLOT_NAME, "w");
setvbuf(gnuplotpipe, NULL, _IONBF, NULL);
//setbuf(gnuplotpipe, NULL);
fprintf(gnuplotpipe,"set term png\n");
fprintf(gnuplotpipe,"set size 720, 480\n");
fprintf(gnuplotpipe,"set size ratio -1\n");
fprintf(gnuplotpipe,"unset key\n");
fprintf(gnuplotpipe,"set xrange [-%d:%d]\n", RANGE+100,RANGE+100);
fprintf(gnuplotpipe,"set yrange [-%d:%d]\n", RANGE+100,RANGE+100);
for(time-steps)
    //do stuff
    fprintf(gnuplotpipe,"plot '-'\n");
    for(all particles)
          // calculate coordinates
          fprintf(gnuplotpipe,"%f %f\n", particle[i]->x, particle[i]->y);
    end for
    fprintf(gnuplotpipe, "e\n");
    //fflush(gnuplotpipe);
end for
_pcloce(gnuplotpipe);
```

and accordingly in linux with `gnuplot -persist` instead of `pgnuplot -persist`, `popen` and `pclose`, and `setbuf` instead of `setvbuf`. This was already with a lot of trial and error.

In linux it is pretty consistent. I can see the `plot '-'` command in console for every time-step and then unintelligible text. Nothing opens. In Windows it is amazing, as sometimes it will work and I get to see the data streaming on the gnuplot "MS Windows" window (I mean not console output and that is amazing in itself as I am not using wgnuplot_pipes.exe). Nothing is plotted. The window closes. Other times for a few time-steps it will plot, but in different windows for every time-step. Sometimes, it will crash or it will work but send unintelligible text.

I am working with 100 particles most of the time. I can have as many as 10,000 time-steps. I don't know if that's a lot. I'm suspecting a cut-off or something in windows, although I'm setting the buffer to NULL. I am working in MSVC in Win7 x64 and Qt in Linux Mint x64 in a VirtualBox. I'm using gnuplot 4.7 (win) and 4.6.0.8 (linux). I have looked pretty extensively in SO and the only problem I found was that `-persist` does not really persist in windows. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the commands in gnuplot directly?  It works for me (in Linux) when going to the x11 device, but png gives me "out of memory for bitmap buffer".

Comment: the png term creates png file output (the random junk you see) You need to pipe that to some app for display.

Comment: Thank you, both of you! The `set term x11` was a nice catch. Also explains why I would get junk with `set term png`. I set the term to `windows` in Win7 and to `X11` in Mint and it worked! It was a basic mistake... Please answer so I can accept and add rep!


This closes my question, but I have another one. The window titled `gplt` appears but it's empty (white) and the coordinates on the lower left corner are -1300, -500 both in Win and Mint. I cannot use the mouse to zoom in or out pressing `u`. So, I cannot see if it's plotting or not. Thank you for the help!

Comment: try turning off all options, let it autorange..also default x11 markers are tiny, use linespoints initially to make easier to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just so the question doesnt go unanswered..this is a python version of your procedure,
with the x11 terminal. It puts up a single window with a silly animation.

Watch though, I wouldnt be at all surprised if some other drivers try to open a window for each frame

```
import subprocess
f=subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/gnuplot','-persist'],
                      stdin=subprocess.PIPE,shell=False)
f.stdin.write('set term x11 \n')
f.stdin.write('set yrange [-2:2]\n')
import math
i=0
d=1
count=0
while count<1000 :
 count+=1
 if abs(i)==50 : d *= -1
 i+=d 
 f.stdin.write('plot \'-\' with linespoints pt 4 ps 2 \n')
 for j in range(0,500):
  f.stdin.write('%f %f\n'%(float(j),math.sin(float(j)/float(abs(i)+1))))
 f.stdin.write('e\n')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'll need to do it in python at some point, so that is really helpful!!